# Calculating current in one branch of circuit

Tags: current, circuit-analysis, current-source, voltage-source

I want to calculate the current labeled in the diagram \$i\$. I am thinking that since there is 3V it would be as straightforward as \$\frac{3V}{6\Omega}\$ for the current in that branch labeled. Is that the correct thinking or am I missing some concept? I see that there is 2A being delivered as well, but would that change my answer?

[image: schematic diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use superposition to solve this circuit.

Superposition means solve for the current i due to the voltage source, with the current source set to 0A (i.e. current source disconnected).  Then, find the current i due to the current source, with the voltage source set to 0V (i.e. voltage source shorted).  Then, add the two together to get the final answer.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Also, if i was to do this using the nodal method, would I consider the entire 3V wire in the first section to be a single node?

Comment: What do you mean by "the entire 3V wire in the first section"?

Comment: top left corner to the intersection where i is.

Comment: When calculating the effects of the current source, you replace the voltage source with a short.  So yes, that would be a single node.